# Validating input in python

Tags: python, validation

Im trying to write a rock paper scissor program where the choice are 1, 2, and 3. I want to validate the input so that any input other than these three choice will print a message saying the input is valid, and ask the user to reinput the data. I have it somewhat working, however, even if i do enter 1 2 or 3, it will still print the message and ask for more input.

```
print("This program simulates a 'rock paper scissor' game.")
print("The rules are as follows: rock beats scissor, paper beats rock, and scissor beats paper. \n")

print("This program simulates a 'rock paper scissor' game.")
print("The rules are as follows: rock beats scissor, paper beats rock, and scissor beats paper. \n")

#get user input
user_choice = input("Please choose from the following:  \n"
                    " 1 for scissor \n"
                    " 2 for rock \n"
                    " 3 for paper. \n")

#validate input so user only enters 1, 2, or 3
while user_choice != 1 or user_choice != 2 or user_choice != 3:
    user_choice = input("Please enter only '1' for scissor, '2' for rock, or '3' for paper: ")

#convert input to int 
int_user_choice = int(user_choice)
```

Comment: `input` returns a `str`, try `while  user_choice != "1"...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the input from a string to an integer if you want to compare it with integers later.  And you can use a list if you want to avoid repeating the logic over and over again.

```
user_choice = int(input("Please choose from the following:  \n"
                    " 1 for scissor \n"
                    " 2 for rock \n"
                    " 3 for paper. \n"))
```

and

```
while user_choice not in [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

After you get the input, you could check if both the input is a valid [digit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) and it is in the valid range and if one of the two conditions do not hold, ask again for an input.

```
valid_choices = {1,2,3}
while not user_choice.isdigit() and not int(user_choice) in valid_choices:
   user_choice = input("Please enter only '1' for scissor, '2' for rock, or '3' for paper: ")
```

or more simply

```
valid_choices = {'1','2','3'}
while not user_choice in valid_choices:
  user_choice = input("Please enter only '1' for scissor, '2' for rock, or '3' for paper: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the entire prompt / validation in a single loop. User doesn't get to continue until the condition is satisfied

```
print("This program simulates a 'rock paper scissor' game.")
print("The rules are as follows: rock beats scissor, paper beats rock, and scissor beats paper. \n")

print("This program simulates a 'rock paper scissor' game.")
print("The rules are as follows: rock beats scissor, paper beats rock, and scissor beats paper. \n")

#get user input
while True:
    user_choice = input("Please choose from the following:  \n"
                    " 1 for scissor \n"
                    " 2 for rock \n"
                    " 3 for paper. \n")

    #validate input so user only enters 1, 2, or 3
    if user_choice in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        int_user_choice = int(user_choice)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours is not correct because input returns of type string and you were checking with type int, so change the type in the loop. Moreover, you cannot use `or` if you want it to terminate when one of the cases is true, in that case, you must use `and`.

```py
print("This program simulates a 'rock paper scissor' game.")
print("The rules are as follows: rock beats scissor, paper beats rock, and scissor beats paper. \n")

print("This program simulates a 'rock paper scissor' game.")
print("The rules are as follows: rock beats scissor, paper beats rock, and scissor beats paper. \n")

#get user input
user_choice = input("Please choose from the following:  \n"
                    " 1 for scissor \n"
                    " 2 for rock \n"
                    " 3 for paper. \n")

#validate input so user only enters 1, 2, or 3

while user_choice != '1' and user_choice != '2' and user_choice != '3':
    user_choice = input("Please enter only '1' for scissor, '2' for rock, or '3' for paper: ")

#convert input to int
int_user_choice = int(user_choice)
```